# How to customize java options of a independent netbeans application?

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, netbeans-platform

i'm developing an application using Netbeans RCP. I have added an option to add a jar to my class path in the `project.properties` file of my platform:

```
run.args.extra=-cp:a ./appclient/glassfish/lib/gf-client.jar
```

The problem i encounter is that is does work when i run it from the Netbeans IDE but not when i try to create a independent application (build for Mac OSX for instance). I hear that the `project.properties` is no longer taken in account when you run an independent application and of course my `appclient` directory containing the jars does not exist anymore in the application package (so my jar is not added to class path).

How can i make this -cp option works for my independent Mac OSX application?

---

EDIT: i was able to create a custom conf file for my independent platform but i can't find a way to add my jar to the class path, i don't know what options to use.

EDIT: i found that i need to you endorsed mechanism to achieve it. So i have added the following command to my app.conf file:

```
J-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/altanis/appclient/glassfish/lib/gf-client.jar
```

But when i run the .app (mac application), i get this error:

```
-J-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/altanis/appclient/glassfish/lib/gf-client.jar: No such file or directory
```

The path is correct. Do i need to make something special to make the JVM aware of this? I followed [this](http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-call-ejb-on-glassfish) tutorial and somewhere in the comments the author says:

> Right, but the package-appclient copies everything for you and you
>   should be able to put it on the classpath using the endorsed
>   mechanism. Unpack the jar created by that and add everything you need
>   from there (the jars) to your application installer. Then you can use
>   the endorsed (-J-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${GFCLIENT_PATH}) mechanism in
>   your app.conf to put it on the application classpath. This way you
>   should be able to deploy it together with your client.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that create a new library is the better way.

1. Create module type library with required jars
2. In your module add dependency to created module (type wrapped library)

Answer (score 0):

You must add entry `Class-path` to you application's `MANIFEST.MF`
For example

```
Class-Path: apache-commons-2.1.jar ejb-api-3.0.jar
```

all this `jars` should be in the root directory of your application
Your appliction should have next structure

```
MyApplication.jar  
/META-INF  
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
/apache-commons-2.1.jar  
/ejb-api-3.0.jar  
/com/package/classes
```

or you can use `jar` tool of JDK to create a jar
read more here [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: @nathan how your application looks like? Compiled classes in jar file? You have executable class? or you deploy application on application server?

Comment: @llya it's just a simple netbeans rcp application, nothing fancy with no MANIFEST.MF. I edited the question because i found something called endorsed mechanism that should help me achieving what i want.